# How were the weightings in the linux load computation chosen?

Tags: linux, kernel, history, load, algorithm

In Linux, the load average is said to be on 1min/5min/15min. The formula used by the kernel is actually an Exponential moving average.

If we define `cpuload(1)` as the first computation of the cpu load 1min, and `active()` as the function returning the number of process in state "running" or "runnable" on the system, then the formula used by the kernel to compute the *nth* cpu load 1min is:

[image]

`cpuload(0)` is 0; it is the value stored in memory before the first execution of `cpuload()`.

My question is, how was the weighting 2<sup>-5.log2(e)/60</sup> chosen? In my opinion, 2<sup>-5/60</sup> would have been better because 1min would have been the half-life of the number of process (because (2<sup>-5/60</sup>)<sup>12</sup> = 1/2).

---

Maybe it's helpful if i post the explicit formula of `cpuload(n)` in addition to the recursive definition above (right-click to see it in full size):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Consider a particular load sample *active(K)*, and how much that sample contributes to *cpuload(K+d)*, for increasing values of *d*.  There are a few key observations:

- *active(K)* is multipled by some weight *W(d)* to determine its contribution to *cpuload(K+d)*.
- *W(d)* is always less than one.
- *W(d)* decreases exponentially as *d* increases.
- computer arithmetic has finite precision.

Together, these points mean that there is some *dmin* such that, for *d>dmin*, *active(K)W(d)=0* and so *active(K)* has no influence on *cpuload(K+d)*.  In short, *cpuload(n)* is only influenced by *dmin* previous samples.

Another way to look at this is that *cpuload(n)* forgets data after a time defined by

- the decay exponent, which defines *dmin*, and
- the sampling frequency.

This final interpretation gives the meaning of the 1-minute, 5-minute, and 15-minute load averages.  The decay and the sampling interval are chosen so that these load averages forget the past after 1, 5, and 15 minutes respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing they wanted the mean lifetime of the contribution of a running process to be one minute.